# Show that $\left|\int^{x+1}_{x}\sin(t^2)dt\right|<\frac1x$ for every positive $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let the function:
$$f(x)=\int^{x+1}_{x}\sin(t^2)dt$$
Prove:

$$|f(x)|<1/x \mbox{ if } x>0$$

Using relationships $\sin(x)<x$ and $\sin(x)\leq1$ for all $x\in R$. I did not arrive at the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Assume $x>0$. One may just integrate by parts as follows
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int^{x+1}_{x}\sin(t^2)dt
\\\\&=\int^{x+1}_{x}\frac{2t\sin(t^2)}{2t}\:dt
\\\\&=\left[\frac{-\cos(t^2)}{2t} \right]^{x+1}_{x}-\int^{x+1}_{x}\frac{\cos(t^2)}{2 t^2}\:dt
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
|f(x)|< \left(\frac1{2x}+\frac1{2(x+1)}+\int^{x+1}_{x}\frac{dt}{2 t^2}\right)=\frac1x
$$ as espected.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\Big|\int_{x}^{x+1}\sin(t^2)\,dt\Big|&\le\int_{x}^{x+1}|\sin(t^2)|\,dt=\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{|\sin(t^2)|2t}{2t}\,dt\le\frac{1}{2x}\int_{x}^{x+1}|\sin(t^2)|2t\,dt=\\
&=\frac{1}{2x}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x+1}}|\sin(s)|\,ds<\frac{1}{2x}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}+\pi}|\sin(s)|\,ds=\frac{1}{2x}\cdot 2=\frac1x.
\end{align}

Comment: In the second line, the second integral's upper bound can be made $\sqrt{x}+2$, and then using $|\sin(s)|\leq 1$ you can get the result. I don't see how you get the equality of the last integral otherwise.

Comment: @Moya For any $a$ we have $\int_a^{a+\pi}|\sin(t)|\,dt=\int_0^{\pi}|\sin(t)|\,dt=\int_0^{\pi}\sin(t)\,dt=[-\cos(t)]_0^\pi=2$ because $|\sin t|$ is $\pi$-periodic.

Comment: @Moya You take the smaller interval, but the larger function, so at the end it becomes the same.